# Unexpected results from query pulling oldest 50 songs in database with unique artists

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a music player system which is supposed to play each song in my database, mostly randomly, before repeating any songs. My problem is, there are some very old songs in the database that are being skipped.

My query is set up to pull the 50 oldest songs in the database but with no duplicate artists.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   spotify_master 
WHERE  days IS NULL 
       AND id NOT LIKE 'random_%' 
       AND type = ? 
       AND autoplay = 1 
GROUP  BY Substring_index(artist, ',', 1) 
ORDER  BY last_played ASC 
LIMIT  50
```

If I remove the `GROUP BY` part, the query actually returns the oldest songs in the database, but it includes duplicate artists.

I'm not sure why this is straight up causing songs to not show up at all, but the oldest song in my database has a timestamp of `2019-10-30 10:55:28`, while this query is selecting songs with a timestamp of only 2 weeks ago or so.

I currently have around 550 songs that haven't played in at 3-6 months, which is 1/4th of all the music it can choose from.

How can I get this query to select the oldest songs in the database with no duplicate artists?

Here is an image of the results of my query as-is (but changed to LIMIT 5)
[image]

Here is an image of the exact same query, except without the `GROUP BY` clause. This returns the expected results with the oldest timestamps, but it also has the potential to return multiple songs from the same artist, which is what I'm trying to avoid.
[image]

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  Your question is also quite unclear.  In one part, you want the 50 oldest songs.  In another, you want different artists.  Which is it?  Also, storing multiple values in a string column is a sign of very poor database design.  You should have a `song_artists` table, with one row per song and artist.

Comment: sample data is simple. Do a 
`select * from spotify_master  limit 10` . Based on that pick the oldest song (instead of the oldest 50) and check how your query works.

Comment: Generally people will jump to help you if you provide all the necessary data using something like sqlfiddle or dbfiddle. At a minimum, we need table structure, sample data, expected result.

Comment: let me know if my answer helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I must preface this by saying I am no MySQL expert.

Generally when you do a `GROUP BY` you group by a list of columns. For the other columns an aggregate function needs to be applied. I assume MySQL is using `any_value`. Thus your      `ORDER BY` will be applied on data that was aggregated rendering it meaningless.

After doing a bit of research, it seems that indeed the values are randomly choosen by MySQL and it is just bad practice. I strongly advise you not to write query like these.

To disallow this, you can say at runtime:

```
SET sql_mode := CONCAT('ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,',@@sql_mode);
```

I think this should do the trick for what you want to achieve:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
       FIRST_VALUE(id) OVER (PARTITION BY Substring_index(artist, ',', 1) ORDER BY last_played ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING ) as id,
       FIRST_VALUE(name) OVER (PARTITION BY Substring_index(artist, ',', 1) ORDER BY last_played ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING ) as name,
       FIRST_VALUE(artist) OVER (PARTITION BY Substring_index(artist, ',', 1) ORDER BY last_played ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING ) as artist,
       FIRST_VALUE(last_played) OVER (PARTITION BY Substring_index(artist, ',', 1) ORDER BY last_played ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING ) as last_played
FROM   spotify_master 
WHERE  days IS NULL 
       AND id NOT LIKE 'random_%' 
       AND type = 'english'
       AND autoplay = 1 
LIMIT  50
```

There is more work involved in making it work prior to MySQL 8 as you will need to partition by hand :

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT    ( 
              CASE Substring_index(artist, ',', 1)
              WHEN @curType 
              THEN @curRow := @curRow + 1 
              ELSE @curRow := 1 AND @curType := Substring_index(artist, ',', 1) END
            ) + 1 AS rank,
            id,
            name, 
            artist,
      Substring_index(artist, ',', 1),
      days,
      type,
      autoplay
  FROM      spotify_master ,
            (SELECT @curRow := 0, @curType := '') r
  ORDER BY  Substring_index(artist, ',', 1), last_played ASC) ManualRankingDueToLackOfPartitioning 
WHERE rank=1 
LIMIT 50
```

What I do is basically parition by `Substring_index(artist, ',', 1)` and order by `last_played`, in this way showing the oldest played song for each artists and picking 50 artists.

If you want to prioritise the oldest last_played songs you just need to add an `ORDER BY`

```
  SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT    ( 
                  CASE Substring_index(artist, ',', 1)
                  WHEN @curType 
                  THEN @curRow := @curRow + 1 
                  ELSE @curRow := 1 AND @curType := Substring_index(artist, ',', 1) END
                ) + 1 AS rank,
                id,
                name, 
                artist,
          Substring_index(artist, ',', 1),
          days,
          type,
          autoplay,
          last_played
      FROM      spotify_master ,
                (SELECT @curRow := 0, @curType := '') r
      ORDER BY  Substring_index(artist, ',', 1), last_played ASC) ManualRankingDueToLackOfPartitioning 
    WHERE rank=1 
    ORDER BY last_played ASC
    LIMIT 50
```

Comment: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(PARTITION BY Substring_index(artist, ',', 1) ORDER BY last_played ASC ROWS BETW' at line 2` - Also, I know it's generally "bad practice" to return _all_ columns, but is there any way to modify this to do so?

Comment: Not sure if it's relevant, but I'm using MySQL version `5.6.44`. I used the SQL I found [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/partitioning.html) to check if partitioning is enabled in my system, and it is.

Comment: Window functions were unfortunatelly introduced in MySQL 8.0.2. When I have a bit of free time I will update my answer for your specific version.

Comment: Your update seems to be _kind of_ working. By this I mean it is returning some of the older timestamps, however, it still isn't returning the oldest ones and the results are a mixture of older timestamps and newer timestamps, and not in the correct order either. Remember, I have ~550 songs with timestamps older than 3 months. Here is an image of my results: https://i.ibb.co/h8MPj0y/2020-05-13-13-59-12-Clipboard.png (There is even several results in there only a few days old)

Comment: You are correct it does what I said it does : ' displays the oldest played song for each artists and picking 50 artists' but not what you wanted 'displaying the oldest songs for 50 different artists'. I will give it another shot later on in the day :)

Comment: Thank you so much! This is perfect!

Answer (score 0):

I would assume this to lump all artists together that don't have a comma separator, as those will all return an empty string.

Comment: At first I was thinking that the query was only returning songs with multiple artists, but I tested this by running the query and checking if the songs returned only had a single artist, and I found that it is actually returning songs with a single artist still.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Does it return more than 1 song with a single artist? Because it's not that the single artist result is gone, it's that they would all get grouped together for the purpose of your distinct functionality.

Comment: I just checked this, and yes, it is returning multiple songs with only a single artist, and also multiple songs with multiple artists.